# setTitle in loadLayout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

I need to **setTitle using loadLayout()** in magento2, i tried follow.

**Core code Controller:**

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->renderLayout();
```

**I overridden controller then change**

```
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Custom title'));
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

its throw **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean**

I refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23876/dynamic-page-title-on-custom-module) its not working for me.

Suggest Me How to set Title using loadlayout.

**Update:**

[image]

I need to set **my custom title** instead of **Catalog Advanced Search**

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara how this magento1 question is duplicate of magento2 can you explain?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepa Please do not blindly close vote questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, override in `module-catalog-search/Controller/Advanced/Result.php`

```
 $this->_view->loadLayout();
 $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle('Test TEst');
 $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

I have tested it works!

Comment: can I use this code in phtml page using object manager

Answer (score 8):

Add below code in your controller:

```
protected $_pageConfig;

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig
    ) {
        $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;
    }

//In execute action add below code

   $this->_view->loadLayout();
   $this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Page title here'));
   $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

Comment: it changed  browser tab title only not change page title suggest me any other way to do this.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E. update image in your question where you want title, so that we can understand. I think above code is enough to set title.

Comment: @BornCoder I update my question

Answer (score 4):

This **title** is called from **Block** override  `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form.php` and `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Result.php`

```
public function _prepareLayout()
    {  
        //add your title here 
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Your title here')); // add title here

    }
```

Comment: if i change  `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced \Result.php`  file only change Browser tab title not a Page title.

Answer (score 2):

That title you want to change is coming from vendor/magento/module-catolog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml

You need to modify the block arguments

There is a referenceBlock "page.main.title" which has the method setPageTitle where the "Catalog Advanced Search" is set.

```
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Catalog Advanced Search</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

You can extend that layout and you can change it with the text you want.

This can be seen in the official Magento 2 documentation [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_block-properties)

Comment: its works fine,   but i need to use catalog advanced result page in multiple purpose. so, i need to dynamically change a page title , suggest me any other way to change dynamically

Comment: This is module specific. So in every other module, you can do on a similar approach. But if you want to do dynamically, I would do it at the template level (within phtml files) and use $block->setPageTitle() method.

Answer (score 1):

Step1 : Get **block name** that is responsible for Title html generation.
This will be :

> page.main.title

Step2 : use `setPageTitle('some tile')`  function of block class to set title value.

Over code will be :

```
$layout=$this->_view->getLayout();
$blockname='page.main.title';
$block = $layout->getBlock($blockname);
$block->setTitle(__('Some page title'));
```